# Find Command Example - OEL7

Tags: linux, shell-script, find

```
find /path -type f -name '*' -not -name "data*" -mtime +1 -delete
```

I want to ask about this command.

As I understand, this command go to path and delete according sysdate-1 all of the files excepting files named like data...

Is this true?

Regards,

Comment: `-name '*'` is redundant: all files have a name. -mtime counts date in units of 24hours without regard to date boundaries, unless you use `-daystart`.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant Hi Paul, sorry for late response. I tried this command: "find /path/path/path -type f -name '*' -mtime +7 -delete" and it did nothing. Is there something missing that I did? Regards.

Comment: To test which file would be deleted, I suggest to use `find /path -depth -type f -not -name "data*" -mtime +1` first, and append -delete if the list of file names is what you expect. Otherwise, errors in your `find` command may result in deleting wrong files.